# How to join these tables with columns that don't always match?

Tags: sql, database-design, powerquery, data-modeling

I have 2 tables: **google_analytics** and **marketing_costs**. How can I join these 2 columns (**google_analytics['source']** with **marketing['medium']**) even tho they don't always match?

[image: Data Model join example]

Comment: that depends on the wanted result there are many joins like LEFT guve it a try and see what happens

Comment: The column names don't have to match, as long as the column values match.

Comment: I don't really get what your question is.  Please give more detail about your requirement

Comment: both datasets have no primary key and I want to join them based on compaign_name. which is called differently in both datasets.

The issue is that for marketing['medium'], I have only 5 distinct values while for google_analytics['source'] I have more than 1000 distinct values. My issue is which cadinality should I use in PowerQuery MODEL to get the accurate values

Comment: This is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking reflect research. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Show what you are able to do. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS DDL is text for an ERD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a shared dimension table, then add a relation

```
let
    Sources = List.Combine({ google_analytics[source],  marketing_costs[platform] }),
    Source = List.Distinct( List.Sort( Sources )),

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
        type table[Name = text], null, ExtraValues.Error),

    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Source Id", 0, 1, Int64.Type)    
in
    #"Added Index"
```